# weekday selection plugin does not set previously selected days

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use this [days selection plugin.](http://codebits.weebly.com/plugins/category/weekline-day-picker)
I'm successfully render this plugin and postit's selection values to the controller (I'm saying this that plugin is loaded and work correctly).
I have problem with understanding how to set predefined values, the ones previously saved or values which I hardcode for this example, like this

```
public ActionResult Demo()
{
    var myModel = new MyModel{ SelectedDaysIndex = "0,1,5" };
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Inside Demo.cshtml there is

```
 <span id="myDays" class="weekDays-dark"></span>

 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedDaysIndex , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Hidden property (`SelectedDaysIndex`) actually holds selected days values and span (`myDays`) renders days selection plugin.

> When page is render selection days does not contain any selected day.

I'm using this inline page script to render day labels and to fetch day selection on users click

```
$("#myDays").weekLine({
    dayLabels: ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "SAT", "SUN"],    
         onChange: function () {
            $("#SelectedDaysIndex").val(
                 $(this).weekLine('getSelected', 'indexes')
             ).trigger("change");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you would want to use the `setSelected` option.

```
$("#myDays").weekLine("setSelected", "0,1,2,3,4");
```

you could get the values from your hidden input or just pass them as a javascript variable in the page itself

Comment: ok, thanks. How coluld I use embedded those model hidden input values inside my javascript code?

Comment: in script tag can print them to a javascript variable, use that variable in code above